# Entity Framework 5 Enum that is built from a db table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums, entity-framework-5

I have those two entities :

[image]

Color entity is mapped to a table of constant values that represent colors.
Code=1, Name="Red"
Code=2, Name="Blue"
And so on...

In Car entity, the Color property is of type int and has a foreign key constraint to the Code property in Color entity. I want to convert the Color property in Car to an Enum, but the Enum should get it's values from Color table.

The Enum could be updated in each build action or an "update model" action in the designer. 
Can this functionality can be achieved ?

Comment: You could probably write a T4 template (*.tt file) to connect to the database and spit out the generated enum, then use an extension to have your template executed before every build. Tools such as Chirpy or Web Workbench afaicr can do this, but other options probably also exist (search in NuGet for options). But I'm not sure it makes sense to do this, since you cannot use the enum safely anywhere in your code (given that the values may change or disappear).

Comment: We've implemented a T4 template that generates enums from DB tables. It works well.

Answer (score 1):

> " but the Enum should get it's values from Color table. "

So whats wrong with what you have? Anyway since you asked...
An enum is by definition inside the assembly.  So as soon as a new color is added to the table you have an outdated Enum. But if you are ok with having upto date at build time. There is a good option.

Clearly the suggestion to use T4 is interesting . But the t4 would need to connect to DB and read it. When T4 goes beyond source generation, it can be easier to use a simple app. Unless of course you are already good at t4. So if t4 is a little hard for this task try:

**A simple side app, that reads the DB and updates the EnumColor.cs** would be plausible.

IE a simple console app.  Place as a pre build step. The **pre-build** reads the DB, rewrites the enum.cs file and the compile/build then follows.

[image]

**Easy Alternative: using a Dictionary which you can extend at runtime **

```
Dictionary<int,string> colors
```

Comment: This solution could work. But you are saying that each time I need to add a new color I could add it both to the table in the db and update the Enum code. Is this a good practice ?

Comment: no just the table.. The simple program would read the table, create/overwrite the simple ColorEnum file and then the compile would happen.  You still need to trigger Build of course.

Answer (score 0):

For me the first question is why? I had a similar technical need but the business need was to help with reporting. Enums works great to make code simpler to read and maintain, but is you have to create a report in say SSRS then you don't have access to the enums (okay I am sure some advanced SSRS users will say you can link in assemblies etc, but that is not the point). We played a bit with a prebuild script (could also run post build) to generate inline scaler function scripts to execute against the db. This way you could do select statements such as:

```
SELECT Model, fColorNameEnum(Color) FROM Car
```

This way you do not have to touch you reports again if you add a new element in your enum. I tend to use enums in the implementation of business logic, typically item status or workflow state. Adding a new option thus require adding new logic which means doing it in code. If you are never going to reason over the color value in code, then what is the reason for wanting to put it in an enum rather than just another linked object?